# I would like to copy cells from a sheet until its last row and paste to another sheet beyond its last row

Tags: vba, copy, paste

Here is what I have done so far. I want to search for the lastrow and copy cells from A5 to G & lastrow and paste this to another sheet to the range F & nextrow and after. nextrow is the variable for the last row of the 2nd sheet plus one.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

lastrow = Worksheets("BackFlush").Cells("BackFlush".Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nextrow = Worksheets("Stock Removed").Cells("Stock Removed").Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row

nextrow = nextrow + 1

Sheets("BackFlush").Range("A5:G & lastrow").Copy
Sheets("Stock Removed").Range("F & nextrow").Paste
```

Any help is desirable.

Comment: Dim lastrow As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

With Sheets("BackFlush")
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Sheets("Stock Removed")
    nextrow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

nextrow = nextrow + 1

Sheets("BackFlush").Range("A5:A & lastrow").Copy
Sheets("Stock Removed").Range("F & nextrow").Paste

Comment: Ijust tried this but there is an error at the "copy" row

Comment: that one is working perfectly




Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim irow1 As Long
Dim irow2 As Long

irow1 = Sheets("BackFlush").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
irow2 = Sheets("Stock Removed").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("BackFlush").Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(irow1, 6)).Copy
Sheets("Stock Removed").Cells(irow2, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

End Sub